# Getting data from different method on typescript ionic 2+

Tags: google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework, geolocation

```
tryGeolocation(){
this.loading.present();
this.clearMarkers();//remove previous markers

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  let pos = {
    lat: resp.coords.latitude,
    lng: resp.coords.longitude
  };
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: this.map,
    title: 'I am here!'
  });
  this.markers.push(marker);
  this.map.setCenter(pos);
  this.loading.dismiss();

}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
  this.loading.dismiss();
}); }
```

i want to get the lat and lng data from geolocation and want put that data to this method.

```
openModal() {
const modal = this.modalCtrl.create('ModalPage');
modal.present(); }
```

how?  #im beginer in programing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass like

```
const modal = this.modalCtrl.create('ModalPage',{lat:72.33,lng:22.54});
```

In next page need to get like below

```
constructor(params: NavParams) 
{
    console.log('lat', params.get('lat'));
    console.log('lng', params.get('lng'));
}
```

For more info please check

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/

Comment: thats is static right?...  i want get lat and lng from trygeolocation() method... i dont understand how to transfer data from different method? help me :(

Comment: Take one global variable and store let pos in that taken variable and when openModal method call use global variable where we store pos

Comment: ooh I understand your explanation, thanks :) ... but I have not been able to implement it into code, can you give example in code? I am very grateful if you can give an example.

Comment: please create sample project in https://stackblitz.com/ so i can edit it

Comment: Project is not running there

Comment: I do not know why ... but on my project is running, I just copy and paste from my project... but on my case is running.... and my problem is on page map.ts